# Read a JSON from a URL using Python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I need an help on reading a JSON from a URL, which has the below JSON in it:

```
{
    "totalItems":2,
    "@href":"/classes/dsxplan:Program",
    "@id":"dsxplan:Program",
    "@mask":"dsplan:MVMask.WorkPackage.Complex",
    "@type":"Collection",
    "@code":200,
    "@context":{
        "dsxplan":"xplan",
        "dsplan":"plan",
        "dspol":"pol",
        "image":{
            "@id":"dspol:image",
            "@type":"@id"
        },
        "dskern":"kern"
    },
    "member":[
        {
            "dsplan:actualType":{
                "@href":"/resources/dsxplan:Program",
                "@id":"dsxplan:Program",
                "@mask":"dskern:Mask.Default",
                "image":"iconProgram.png"
            },
            "dskern:owner":{
                "@href":"/resources/dskern:Person.Creator",
                "@id":"dskern:Person.Creator",
                "@mask":"dskern:MVMask.Person.Complex",
                "dsplan:actualType":{
                    "@href":"/resources/foaf:Person",
                    "@id":"foaf:Person",
                    "@mask":"dskern:Mask.Default"
                }
            },
            "dspol:modificationDate":"2017-09-08T17:54:36.786Z",
            "@href":"/resources/dsxplan:DSLCProgram.R-399",
            "@id":"dsxplan:DSLCProgram.R-399",
            "@mask":"dsplan:MVMask.WorkPackage.Complex",
            "@etag":"7412df19-1dde-4245-b40b-5dd86dbbe3f1"
        },
        {
            "dsplan:actualType":{
                "@href":"/resources/dsxplan:Program",
                "@id":"dsxplan:Program",
                "@mask":"dskern:Mask.Default",
                "image":"iconProgram.png"
            },
            "dskern:owner":{
                "@href":"/resources/dskern:Person.Creator",
                "@id":"dskern:Person.Creator",
                "@mask":"dskern:MVMask.Person.Complex",
                "dsplan:actualType":{
                    "@href":"/resources/foaf:Person",
                    "@id":"foaf:Person",
                    "@mask":"dskern:Mask.Default"
                }
            },
            "dspol:modificationDate":"2017-09-08T17:54:36.786Z",
            "@href":"/resources/dsxplan:xComModel2017program.R-394",
            "@id":"dsxplan:xComModel2017program.R-394",
            "@mask":"dsplan:MVMask.WorkPackage.Complex",
            "@etag":"7412df19-1dde-4245-b40b-5dd86dbbe3f1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I just need to read this json from a link provided. I tried the below code:

```
import urllib.request
request= urllib.request.Request("https://dummy_link")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
input = (response.read().decode('utf-8'))
json.loads(input)
```

This code throws me this error:
"JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 9 column 1 (char 12)"

Could you please help me get this right? I really appreciate the help.!!

Comment: Just swap to the `requests` module and call `.json()` on the response

Comment: Can you show us what `input` looks like?

Comment: @roganjosh - swap requests with .json(). I didn't really get this. Could you please update the code and show it to me please?

Comment: @birryree - the json which I pasted in the question is the input using a link (which would not be accessible to you)

Comment: I understand that, but you also read it into the `input` variable. Can you print that out and put that into your question? It might look different from what your example is.

Comment: I'm suggesting you use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module. The first example uses `.json()`. It's much more simple than urllib

Comment: You don't need to decode your content to UTF-8. `json.loads` can load a bytes string.

Comment: @birryree - I now understand what you meant.!! I printed that and the authentication of the link fails and hence gives a html. I'm working on the authentication part, once I am done with that will update the post accordingly.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE - I will give that a try once I am done with the authentication of the link. Thanks.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) library which is more simple than urllib:

For instance:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://dummy_link')
obj = r.json()
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use urllib, you can do as below:

```
import urllib.request
import json

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://dummy_link") as f:
    content = f.read()

obj = json.loads(content)
```

There is no need to convert the binary content to unicode string.

There is an [urllib howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#urllib-howto) in the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the Response. I will need sometime to figure out the new issue encountered and get back on your proposed solution. I hope it works and will update you accordingly. Thank you for the efforts.!!